# Firewire 800 cable for new iMac

Tags: firewire, imac

Which one of these [**cables**](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=firewire%20800%20cable%20imac&x=0&y=0) is the one I have to buy to connect a FireWire 400 device I have to the FireWire 800 port of the new 27" iMac?

Comment: Firewire 800 is always the 9-pin, so it depends which Firewire 400 is on your device. What device are you looking to connect?

Comment: my device uses one of these regular firewire connectors, the one that is a rectangle with one curved side... I think it is a regular 6 pin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [first cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Neet%C2%AE-FireWire-Cable-IEEE-1394b/dp/B00316V6LW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308251581&sr=8-1) will work for you. The Firewire 400 with the curved side is 6-pin.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers 1, 4, 5, 7 & 8 should all work. Of course the adapters will assume that you have a FW400 cable already.